# Android image upload, error in remove image operation

Tags: android, image-uploading

I'm working on android to make an app that able to upload some photos to server. My problem here is when I want to completely remove an image from the list. I can remove the view from image view but when I upload the image. I got two image, one is the previous photo and another is the last photo I set on the image after remove. (Notes : image resources are from gallery). Below are my codes

Code to set a photo to image view

```
if(image.getDrawable() == null)
        {
            image.setImageBitmap(imageUpload);
            imageUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            image_data = baos.toByteArray();
            encoded_image_1 = Base64.encodeBytes(image_data);
        }
        else if(image2.getDrawable() == null)
        {
            image2.setImageBitmap(imageUpload);
            imageUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            image_data = baos.toByteArray();
            encoded_image_2 = Base64.encodeBytes(image_data);
        }
        else if(image3.getDrawable() == null)
        {
            image3.setImageBitmap(imageUpload);
            imageUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            image_data = baos.toByteArray();
            encoded_image_3 = Base64.encodeBytes(image_data);
        }
```

Code to remove image

```
else if(image3.getDrawable() != null)
            {
                image3.setImageBitmap(null);
                encoded_image_3 = null;
            }
            else if(image2.getDrawable() != null)
            {
                image2.setImageBitmap(null);
                encoded_image_2 = null;
            }
            else if(image.getDrawable() != null)
            {
                image.setImageBitmap(null);
                encoded_image_1 = null;
            }
```

Code to upload image

```
params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_1", encoded_image_1));
                params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_2", encoded_image_2));
                params_p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_3", encoded_image_3));
```

I appreciate any help from everyone, thanks.

Comment: use `FileBody` to send images to server, not `Base64`, this is much faster and more efficient

Comment: what do you mean by efficient? I'm talking about how to remove an image completely from view and assign a new one.

Comment: this is just an advice, actual answer I posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if every `encoded_image_*` is null before adding it to parameters bundle. If the one wich should be null is not null - debug step by step removement process and find, why programm does not go into `encoded_image_* = null` section.

Comment: When I try to debug step by step I found that it assigning to another image view, so it has 4 image when instead of 3. Do you have any idea to make it really null or something like that?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto Can you post more code? In the question you said there are exactly 3 `params_p.add`, so it's unclear for me, how the forth may appear.

Comment: Actually there are 6 images, the images that send to the server are depend on how many image that assigned by user. This is my code  http://pastebin.com/PqhGxRL2

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto Look - you set "image_data_*" to `null`, but then refer to `encoded_image_*`(it is unchanged) when sending images. In yout question there is no such mistake, but in the code you posted in the last comment - it is

Comment: Actually I've changed the code, when I write my code in this question, it's not work. Then I change to image_data_* and it still do the same.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto You may try this: instead of checking if image drawable is null, keep null-s and not nulls ImageViews in two lists, so when you add the picture, take the last element of nulls and put it into null's. On remove make it reverse. In such way you can manually control whenever image is actually null and should not be sent.

Comment: well thanks, I had solved the problem, I also need to use the `bitmap.recycle();` to free the resource. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try imageUpload.recycle()

Comment: Thanks, but it still do the same.